# Replicate Oracle's `TRUNC(DATE, 'WW')` behaviour in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I need to convert this to postgres:

```
TRUNC(CAST((SYSTIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'US/Eastern') AS DATE), 'WW')
```

This will return 22-APR-20

I tried

```
(DATE_TRUNC('WEEK', CAST((CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'US/Eastern') AS DATE)) - interval '1 week')
```

but it returns april 20.

Comment: Why you expecting it to be 22-april? You are truncating on week boundary which is 19-apr or 20-apr depending on your preference.

Comment: Yes, i'm expecting april 22. I won't know why, but the original Oracle code I posted is returning april 22, so I need postgres to do the same

Comment: @maxtaldykin Because "WW Same day of the week as the first day of the year" https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions230.htm#i1002084

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
user=# select date_trunc('year', now())::date + (to_char(now(), 'WW')::int - 1) * 7;
  ?column?  
------------
 2020-04-22
(1 row)
```

### How it works

- `date_trunc('year', now())::date` returns first day of the year
- `to_char(now(), 'WW')::int - 1` current week number (starting from zero)
- first day of year + current week * 7 days = closest preceding date with same day of week as the first day of the year.

Comment: I need it to return april 22. The Oracle code that I posted returns april 22, so I need postgres to do the same.

Comment: `WW` truncates date to the nearest previous day same to the first day of week of the year. So for `2020-04-30`it should to return `2020-04-29`

Comment: @Abelisto, fixed it. Thanks for clarification.

Comment: @max taldykin I would have never figured that out